# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in maven

Tags: maven, jersey

I have a jersey WS project with maven, where I am trying to use an external jar, abc.jar, inside which I have com.x.y.z package containing public class MyException. When I run that with "mvn -X exec:java", I see the following exception in the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.x.y.z.MyException
>
> > ```
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
> > ```
> >
> > > at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > > at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> > > > ```

This is what I have in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    ............
    ............
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.x</groupId>
        <artifactId>y.z</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1</version>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/abc.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am not sure if I need some additional configuration or what I have is not correct. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!